# Ember.js: How to show the current content of Model on template which is in modal pop up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I am working on an application which is using ember.js for UI side development. The application requires all the actions to be performed on the pop up modal window. So I am creating one object with all the necessary javascript model to be shown on that pop-up model. This is working fine, but when we are on that modal pop-up, if we change the content of the javascript model, the latest model content is not shown on the list. The code snippet is as follows: the javascript model is-

```
App.ModelToShow = DS.Model.extend({
  name : DS.attr(),
  label : DS.attr(),
});
```

So when I am calling the model template from App.js, it goes like this

```
obj = { modelToShow : this.store.find('modelToShow')};
this.send('openModal', 'myTemplate', obj);
```

template has a table where i show all the content of the "modelToShow" in rows. The openModal used above is used to open the template in modal window with obj to display.
So now on this page if i do some action i.e. changeContent then its not actually changing it. My action method is as follows:

```
 App.ModelToShowController = App.ModalController.extend({
   actions:{
     changeContent : function(){
        self.store.push('modelToShow', {
            id : 2,
            name : 'radhe',                     
            label : 'new label'
        });
        self.store.find('modelToShow', 1).then(function (modelToShow) {
            modelToShow.destroyRecord(); 
        });
    }
   }
});
```

To my surprise if I delete the record, thats reflecting in model, but not the object I pushed, although that is available in store if I debug with ember plugin. And this destroyRecord I am using is sending a server web service call to delete that record, how to avoid that and just delete the record from the model available in store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`store.unloadRecord(modelToShow);` will remove it from the store only

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_unloadRecord

I don't think pushing a record loads it into the store, I think it just caches it, you might try finding the record after you push it.

```
    self.store.push('modelToShow', {
        id : 2,
        name : 'radhe',                     
        label : 'new label'
    });
    self.store.find('modelToShow', 2);
```

Comment: thanks a lot man, this solves the delete call problem, but still unable to populate the record i pushed to store. I tried update instead of push, still no use.

Comment: You might need to the prime the store for that record by calling find by id

Comment: its there in store, it is pushing it. I have tried :
var someObject = self.store.all('modelToShow');     this.set('tableContent',someObject);   
this is working for me now